# Native Italian words still spelled with a 'j'?

Tags: orthography, spelling

There was a trend in the past of spelling semi-consonantal initial *i* (`/j/`) with a *j*:

> - *jeri* / *ieri*
> - *jod* / *iod*, *yod*
> - <s>*juta* / *iuta*</s> (loanword)
> - *jota* / *iota*
> - *jato* / *iato*
> - *jella* / *iella*
> - *jena* / *iena*
> - *jodio* / *iodio*
> - *jonico* / *ionico*
> - *jattanza* / *iattanza*
> - *jettare*, *jettatura*, *jettatore* / *iettare*, *iettatura*, *iettatore*

and similarly inter-vocal *i*:

> - *aja* / *aia*
> - *bujo* / *buio*
> - *guajo* / *guaio*
> - *notajo* / *notaio*
> - *Savoja* / *Savoia*
> - *alleluja* / *alleluia*
> - *fidejussione* / *fideiussione*
> - *pajo*, *paja* / *paio*, *paia*
> - *ajola*, *ajuola* / *aiola*, *aiuola*
> - *noja, annojare* / *noia, annoiare*
> - *scojolo*, *scojattolo* / *scoiattolo*

and additionally replacing plural suffix *-ii* (of *-io*) (to distinguish homophones from plural *-i* (of *-o*)):

> - *varj* / *varij*, *varii*, *varî*, *vari*
> - *genj* / *genii*, *genî*, *geni*
> - *occhj* / *occhii*, *occhi*
> - *viaggj* / *viaggii*, *viaggi*
> - *studj*
> - *ufficj*
> - *principj*
> - *beccaj*

but contemporarily, this orthography seems to have only been retained in a few proper nouns and latinisms:

> - *Jesi*, *Jonio*, *Jesolo*, *Ajaccio*, *Letojanni*, *l’Aja*
> - *Jacopo*, *Jonio*, *Jole*, *Jannacci*, *Jolanda* (*Iolanda*), *Jago* (*Iago*, *Yago*)
> - *Jacuzzi*, *Jovine*, *Jacobelli*, *Jacoviello*, *Jaja*, *Ojetti*, *Ajello*, *Scajola*, *Pistoj*, *Rejna*
> - *Juventus*, *juventino* (*iuventino*), *juniores*

and transcription of regional languages' words:

> - *ajo* (Romanesco, cognate with *aglio*)
> - *naja* (from Friulian *naie*, Old Venetian *naia*)

---

Apart from these proper nouns, **are there any native Italian words still commonly spelled with a *j*?**

---

**Sources**

<sup>• [*The Tuscan Master; Or a New and Easy Method of Acquiring a Perfect Knowledge of the Italian Language in a Short Time, Divided into Two Parts...*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=kmFgAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA208&lpg=PA208&dq=j), Dr. Marcello Guelfi Borzacchini</sup>

<sup>• http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/j-j/</sup>

Comment: Nice question! I'm going to be the annoying one and ask what's your definition of *native* Italian words (if you go back enough most of them come from a different language anyways...). Would "used by an Italian writer before the year 1700" be ok?

Comment: Ah, yes haha - that seems fine for the purposes of my curiosity, but feel free to be as loose with the definition as you like. I mainly just wanted to avoid obvious global calques, like *jazz*, *judo*, *jeans* etc

Comment: Also, and then I'll stop being a pedant, am I correct in assuming that you want to exclude words that evolved from a loanword (*jazzista*, *junghiano*...) in the time between the borrowing and today?

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't particularly thinking of such derivatives either, but feel free to include them as an addendum if you like :)

Comment: I agree with Denis's perplexity: what is a _native_ Italian word? If we take the before-1700 definition, a good starting point would be to perform a search for “*j*” in, say, the third edition (1691) of the Crusca (http://www.lessicografia.it/ricerca_libera.jsp). Unfortunately, it does not seem to allow for fine-tuned searches, so many of the results returned –
 hundreds of them – are plurals in “-j” (occhj, vizj, savj...), which already by themselves attest that it was considered a full part of Italian orthography.

Comment: With no less patience, and loosening quite a bit our later endpoint, we may have a look at what [Tommaseo](http://www.tommaseobellini.it/#/items) thought about “J”. At least, it is easy to get the “J”-lemmas.

Comment: Tommaseo can be searched slightly better in the (not free) Zingarelli application. For instance, the first results for the lemmas in which * j * appears are “abbajare” and its derivates, “abbeveratojo” and similar words (abbigliatojo, abbocatojo...), and more than 2000 more (just lemmas, not inflexed forms).

Comment: These are just starting points to be checked against contemporary use, of course.

Comment: A more 'concrete' criterion for the kind of words I'm looking for might be this: **words containing 'j' where the j corresponds to `/i/`, `/i:/` or `/j/`.** I.e. not `/dʒ/` as in *jazz, jeans, jeep, judo* or `/ʒ/` as in *abat-jour, déjà-vu* (although this would catch 'false positives' like German influenced *junghiano* etc)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apart from the vague suggestions I gave in the comments, perhaps the nearest to an actual answer is here. The digital version of Zingarelli dictionary allows some quite refined searches. It is mostly a vocabulary of contemporary use, not a historical one, so one of the requisites is satisfied by default.

By searching the the present (2018) edition for lemmas including a “j” (just lemmas, not inflexed forms) and asking for the century of first occurrence to be at most the 17th century, we get very little, and probably nothing that qualifies:

- bijou
- dagli (because of Roman variant “daje”)
- fideiussione (because of the variant form “fidejussione”; the same for “fideiussore”)
- foglietta (a volume measure for wine and oil, because of Roman variant “fojetta”)
- j (as a lemma in itself)
- junior
- navaja
- ragià (because of variant form “rajah”)

For the sake of curiosity, adding the 18th century only yields “acajou”, “jacquerie” and “Tokaj”, while in the 19th century a first tide of foreign terms began, from “abat-jour” to “navajo” (with, in last alphabetical position a curious, Neapolitan “scetavajasse”).

So, much as I personally love the letter “j” and would use it everywhere, I guess the answer to your question is a firm no (give or take a wandering fidejussore).

Comment: For what it's worth, I'm pretty sure the plural *principij* is still used somewhere, but I'd be lying if I said it's common used. I'm surprised by the lack of *naja* (but that might be because it is a word that entered Italian in the 20th century with the Great War)

Comment: Indeed, @DenisNardin, Zingarelli gives 1918 as the year of the first attested use of *naja*.