# Uso della lettera "j" nella parola bojate

Tags: orthography, spelling

In un messaggio su Twitter del Dottor Burioni ho letto la seguente cosa:

> Nella scienza si discute, eccome! Non sulla terra piatta e
>   sull'autismo causato dai vaccini (***bojate***), ma su un mondo senza
>   zanzare, che oltre a essere fastidiose trasmettono infezioni che
>   causano centinaia di migliaia di morti.

Mi incuriosisce l'uso della *j* all'interno della parola bojate.

Su Treccani boiate viene scritto con la *i* e non sembra esserci la variante con la *j*.

Altre parole tipo fidejussione e polizza o obbligazione fidejussoria si trovano scritte in entrambe le forme.

Qualcuno saprebbe dirmi se è corretto utilizzare bojate?

Comment: Penso si usasse per indicare il suono semiconsonantico /j/. Adesso non si usa molto, mi pare però di averla vista qualche volta (mi vengono in mente alcuni testi di Pirandello).

Comment: Domanda correlata: https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/9220/native-italian-words-still-spelled-with-a-j.

Comment: Personalmente preferirei che nelle domande ci astenessimo da apprezzamenti ironici (o fossero anche seri) come quell'“esimio”.

Comment: @DaG Esimio è un esempio di rispetto e non è assolutamente ironico. E per carità, ogni opinione è comunque degna di rispetto.

Comment: Ironico o non ironico (infatti contemplavo anche la possibilità che fosse serio), io mi asterrei da apprezzamenti. Roberto Burioni ha scritto XXX, Mario Rossi ha scritto YYY etc. Non sarebbe meglio?

Comment: Modificato. Cerchiamo di essere costruttivi ;)

Comment: Perfetto, grazie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***[Google Books](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=bojata%2Cboiata&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbojata%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cboiata%3B%2Cc0)*** mostra entrambi gli usi, anche se ***bojata*** è  molto meno comune di ***boiata***.

Un esempio abbastanza recente da [Torquato...e altre storie](https://books.google.it/books?id=BjT80yUkHhgC&pg=PA62&dq=%22bojata%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjg8PHyt5XdAhXEFIgKHfBhC6MQ6AEIRTAG#v=onepage&q=%22bojata%22&f=false) di Pietro Cimino, 2005:

> Sì insomma er tarlo nella mente: ***sarà un successo o 'na bojata?*** - Tranquillo, ministro, non te le ricordi le grandi file in visita a El Greco, Marc Chagall, i Bronzi di Riace, o anche solo la processione quotidiana ai Musei Vaticani

Per quanto riguarda l’uso della lettera J in italiano, [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/j/) dice:

> ***L’italiano si servì invece del segno j con due funzioni diverse: tra vocali o all’inizio di parola davanti ad altra vocale*** per indicare il valore semiconsonantico dell’i (per es., jeri); in fine di parola, come terminazione del plurale dei nomi in -io atono (per es., varj) per evitare confusioni, in qualche caso, con altre parole (per es., vari plur. di varo).
>
> ***In entrambe le funzioni, l’uso dell’j in parole italiane è quasi interamente scomparso tra la seconda metà del 19° e la prima del 20° sec.***; è tuttora conservato ufficialmente nella scrittura di cognomi (per es., Ojetti, tale essendo la forma registrata dagli uffici anagrafici) e nomi propri (per es., Ajaccio). Molti conservano l’j iniziale, senza un criterio fisso (per es., Jacopo).

Comment: Nella tua prima citazione mi sembra che l'autore stia trascrivendo del dialetto romano, non dell'italiano standard. Quindi non mi sembra un buon esempio per supportare l'esistenza di "bojata" in italiano.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni: Non avverto differenze fonetiche fra “boiata” in italiano standard e in romanesco. Tu sì?

Comment: @DaG Neanch'io avverto differenze fonetiche, ma non mi sembra questo il punto. Semmai dovremmo parlare di regole di spelling.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni: D'accordo, ma non esiste un'ortografia del romanesco: da Belli a Pascarella, a Pasolini e ai contemporanei, ognuno fa un po' di testa sua basandosi sull'ortografia dell'italiano standard (integrandola solo per i suoni e combinazioni di suoni non standard, come /ʃ/ intervocalico).

Comment: @DaG Mi sembra comunque chiaro (da non-esperto e non-romano) che la 'j' semiconsonantica è molto più usata per scrivere il romanesco che l'italiano: es. *daje*, *mejo*.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni: In effetti, di fatto sì, anche se non c'è un vero motivo “scientifico”. Chissà come è cominciato questo uso.

Answer (score 2):

Riguardo all'uso del grafema *j*, nella sezione I.151 del suo libro *Italiano* (editato per la prima volta nel 1997), Luca Serianni afferma:

> Il grafema *j* è stato tradizionalmente impiegato fino agl'inizi del nostro secolo – ma non regolarmente – per rappresentare /j/ in posizione iniziale o intervocalica (*jeri*, *notajo*; ma non **bjanco*) e, più spesso, per il plurale dei nomi in *-io* (*studio*-*studj*: uso accolto nella 5ª edizione del *Vocabolario della Crusca*, 1863-1923: cfr. MIGLIORINI 1963a: 669). 
>   Per indicare la semiconsonante nei nomi comuni *j* ha goduto di qualche fortuna novecentesca: ne fa uso regolare Pirandello  (per esempio, da *Enrico IV*: *guajo* II 11, *t'ajuteremo* 14, *appajono* 41, *sajo* 49, ecc.); esempi sporadici in altri scrittori (Cecchi, Gadda, citati in SATTA 1981: 43; *ajuto* in Deledda, *L'incendio nell'uliveto*, 41, ecc.). 
>   Nei nomi propri *j* regge discretamente, ma solo in posizione iniziale, in alcuni toponimi: *Jonio*, *Jugoslavia*, *Jacurso*, *Jelsi*, *Jenne*, *Jerzu*, *Jesi*, *Jesolo*, *Joppolo*; e in primi nomi quali *Jacopo*, *Jolanda*, *Jole*, *Jone*. Ancora più stabile *j* iniziale di primi nomi esotici o esotizzanti (*Jader*, *Jago*) e *j* iniziale o interna di cognomi (*Jacobini*, *Jannaco*, *Jorio*, *Jovine*, *Lojacono*, *Lojodice*, *Ojetti*, *Scialoja*, *Bajlo*, *Majno*, *Rajna*, ecc.). 
>   Peraltro tutte le forme citate ammettono variani con *i*. Anzi, «si può dire in generale che non esistano casi in cui *j* non possa essere sostituita da un semplice *i*», tant'è che «nell'uso dei dizionari, delle enciclopedie e d'altri repertori alfabetici prevalente in Italia [...] le lettere *i* e *j* sono mescolate insieme e trattate come lettera unica agli effetti dell'ordinamento alfabetico delle voci» (MIGLIORINI-TAGLIAVINI-FIORELLI 1969: XXIV-XXV).

Quindi, da quanto si può leggere in questa spiegazione, non credo che scrivere "bojate" si possa considerare scorretto, ma non è certamente la forma ortografica prevalente nell'attualità.

Comment: La forma ortografica "bojata" appare in una lettera di Calvino a Vittorini pubblicata nel volume [*I libri degli altri*](https://books.google.es/books?id=dUFdAAAAMAAJ&q=bojata+questo&dq=bojata+questo&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi2zfzkiZXdAhVOYVAKHU8SBGM4ChDoAQgQMAE).